# MariaDB subtract from detail table or return master value if no data in detail

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Mariadb  master detail  table.

My Master has :

```
ID
Name
Status
Quantity
Date
```

And Detail has :

```
ID
IDMSTR
Quantity
Date
```

I have a query now that subtracts the quantity from the master table based on the quantities
mentioned in detail records Master.ID = Detail.IDMSTR the remaining total :

```
SELECT
        itm.ID,
        itm.Name ,
        (Max(itm.Quantity) - SUM(itd.Quantity)) AS Totalq
        FROM Master itm
        INNER JOIN Detail itd
        ON itm.ID = itd.IDMSTR
        WHERE itm.Status  = 1
        GROUP BY itm.ID DESC
        HAVING Totalq >= 200
```

My problem is that the query returns values only when there is a record in the detail table with
quantity  and I'm looking to find a way to have also the total quantity of the master record when there is no detail record.
Is that something possible somehow ?

Thanks

Comment: Try LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT itm.ID, itm.Name ,
       (Max(itm.Quantity) - COALESCE(SUM(itd.Quantity), 0)) AS Totalq
FROM Master itm LEFT JOIN
     Detail itd
     ON itm.ID = itd.IDMSTR
WHERE itm.Status = 1
GROUP BY itm.ID DESC
HAVING Totalq >= 200;
```

Comment: You're correct there is typo in the parenthesis  if you want to edit for others. (Sometimes I feel stuck ,  I have already tried COALESCE  but didn't think about LEFT JOIN) Thanks mate !!!